# Changing web app's base url into host's subdomain

Tags: node.js, nginx, web-applications, webserver, reverse-proxy

I want to deploy some web applications on different ports on the same host, with nginx reverse proxy.

So my configuration file is like this;

```
server_name         foo.bar.com

location /app1/ {
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
}

location /app2/ {
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:6000/;
}

...
```

They work mostly fine, but there's a problem with one app.

It's a nodejs application and it has some functions like `location.href = "/baz"` that change current session's url from `http://foo.bar.com/app` into `http://foo.bar.com/baz` and cause Not Found errors.

That application is quite complicated and not written by me, so modifying it is quite hard.

Is there any way to change the application's base url into `http://foo.bar.com/` so that make it work as `http://foo.bar.com/app/baz`, not `http://foo.bar.com/baz`?